# Are knife/grenade kills included in bloodthirsty medals for a certain weapon?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

To unlock a camo, one of the achievements often is: Get 5 or 10 bloodthirsty medals with the weapon the camo is for.  My question is whether or not you can have the gun as your primary, but use grenades or knife kills to get some of the 5 kills required to get a bloodthirsty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not included.

If you read the camo description, it says (for the Type 25) "using only the Type 25" which means all kills need to come from the weapon.

I've been working my way through all the assault rifles and eventually had to unequip my lethals since I would get a few kills, get in a desperate situation, instinctively throw a semtex and potentially ruin my bloodthirsty medal.  My other mistake was using my hunter killer before getting that fifth kill then trying frantically to get that fifth kill before it hit someone (I typically died in that period of time).

Comment: Best way to go to make sure you go through this camo fast enough is to unequip your lethals as you said, and use non killing killstreaks (usually, I'd go with UAV, counter-UAV, Orbital VSAT)